# Animate UIStackView views into centre

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I have 5 buttons inside a `UIStackView`. One of these is centred. Upon pressing and holding the centre button I want to animate all the other buttons into the centre and hide them. Then when I release the centre button I want to animate them backout from the centre to where they originally were.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
private func transform(views: [UIView], toIdentity isIdentity: Bool) {
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        for view in views {
            if isIdentity {
                view.transform = .identity
            } else {
                view.center.x = self.view.center.x
            }
            
            view.isHidden = !isIdentity
        }
    }
}
```

This works, but when `isIdentity` is false, the buttons all jump to outside the parent view and then move into the centre.

I also tried putting this code inside the animation block. This avoids the weird jumpy issue, but they move further across than the center.

```
let delta = self.view.center.x - view.center.x
view.transform = isIdentity ? .identity : view.transform.translatedBy(x: delta, y: 0)
```

Why is this and how can I solve this?

Comment: This is probably not the right approach... You have 5 buttons in a horizontal row? And when you tap-and-hold the center button you want the other 4 to "slide to the middle" and hide behind the center button?

Comment: Yes but not hide the centre button, that needs to be visible. The other 4 need to be hidden. If this isn’t the right approach, what is?

Comment: There are a few issues you'll be dealing with trying to embed the buttons in a stack view. Are you laying this out in Storyboard or via code? Are the buttons all the same width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple ways you can do this, but here's an approach using a stack view.

Assuming we've laid out in Storyboard 5 buttons in a stack view with these properties:

```
Axis: Horizontal
Alignment: Fill
Distribution: Fill Equally
Spacing: 8
```

(Spacing can be changed as desired)

Try this code:

```
class ButtonAnimViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var buttonsStackView: UIStackView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // we want the outer buttons to "slide in behind" the center button
        //  so we need to custom set their z-orders
        buttonsStackView.arrangedSubviews[0].layer.zPosition = 0
        buttonsStackView.arrangedSubviews[1].layer.zPosition = 1
        buttonsStackView.arrangedSubviews[2].layer.zPosition = 4
        buttonsStackView.arrangedSubviews[3].layer.zPosition = 3
        buttonsStackView.arrangedSubviews[4].layer.zPosition = 2
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func doCollapse(_ sender: Any) {
        // verbose for clarity
        let btn1 = buttonsStackView.arrangedSubviews[0]
        let btn2 = buttonsStackView.arrangedSubviews[1]
        let btn3 = buttonsStackView.arrangedSubviews[2]
        let btn4 = buttonsStackView.arrangedSubviews[3]
        let btn5 = buttonsStackView.arrangedSubviews[4]
        
        // calculate translationX distance for each button to the center button
        let xDistance1 = btn3.center.x - btn1.center.x
        let xDistance2 = btn3.center.x - btn2.center.x
        
        let xDistance4 = btn3.center.x - btn4.center.x
        let xDistance5 = btn3.center.x - btn5.center.x
        
        // animate the transforms
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            btn1.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: xDistance1, y: 0.0)
            btn2.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: xDistance2, y: 0.0)
            btn4.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: xDistance4, y: 0.0)
            btn5.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: xDistance5, y: 0.0)
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func doExpand(_ sender: Any) {
        // verbose for clarity
        let btn1 = buttonsStackView.arrangedSubviews[0]
        let btn2 = buttonsStackView.arrangedSubviews[1]
        let btn4 = buttonsStackView.arrangedSubviews[3]
        let btn5 = buttonsStackView.arrangedSubviews[4]

        // animate transforms back to identity
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            btn1.transform = .identity
            btn2.transform = .identity
            btn4.transform = .identity
            btn5.transform = .identity
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

---

**Edit**

For reference, a standard behavior of `UIStackView` - one which is helpful in many cases - is what happens when you *hide* an arranged subview.

While the subview remains, its frame is ***removed*** from the stack view's arrangement.

So, if you have for example two views in a subview like this, with Leading / Trailing == 40 and Distribution == Fill Equally:

[image]

and you then set `viewB.isHidden = true`, the result will be:

[image]

As you have found, if you want the view to not be visible, but have it continue to affect the layout, you need to set its `.alpha = 0` instead of hiding it.

Comment: Good spot with the zPosition, but I think this is essentially what I have. Except my stackview is laid out through storyboard, and it's alignment is center and distribution is fill. The views are different widths.

Comment: This works. I've realised that it's because `isHidden` isn't set in your code. If I use my original code and remove the setting of the `isHidden` property it also works. Now I've just moved that to a completion block and set the alpha instead. Weird!

Comment: @Tometoyou - I added a little clarification... see the **Edit** at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your stack view is centered? I can't see why the translation code wouldn't work. Maybe try creating the Delta from the centerView rather than the actual view. Note: The problem in the first animation is that it's updating the center and then trying to undo that update with a transform which won't work, it would need to update the frame back to the original position.

```
let delta = centerButton.center.x - view.center.x
view.transform = isIdentity ? .identity : view.transform.translatedBy(x: delta, y: 0)
```

Comment: I tried this too. Actually I figured out that it's because `isHidden` is set within the animation block that it went weird. If I move that to a completion block and set the alpha of the views inside the animation block instead it's fine!